# how to 'ignore the data and leave the instance as it is' in a ModelSerializer update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a field in my models that is an ImageField and every time I try to update a data using the browsable API. The API returns an error for my ImageField which is **The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.** when it's empty but in the instance *it is not*.

How can I *ignore the data and leave the instance as it is* when updating? But when I upload an image in the imagefield, no error returns.

Model

```
class Report(models.Model):
    # other fields
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="reports/image-report/", max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
```

Serializer

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # other fields
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=True, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = "__all__"

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # other fields
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

Viewset

```
class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser) # for uploading attachments
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
```

Comment: Your goal here is for the image to be optional in an update?

Comment: Sorry for not including a goal or desired output in my question it's been a long day. Yes, that is my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, I was able to resolve the issue by adding the **required=False**